# Oracle's motives in the Matrix trilogy

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-matrix, the-matrix-reloaded, the-matrix-revolutions

What does the Oracle wish for? Disorder? If she supports humans then she should help destroy the Matrix. If she does not, then she should mislead Neo and make the machines win.
In the end of The Matrix Revolutions, she seems pretty content. Why? Because the war was over? Is that all she wanted from the start?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not the first matrix, it's the sixth one and Oracle helped Architect to build this one. From the failure of previous matrix, Oracle and Architect given the humans 'free will'. So Oracle  always in support of free will for Humans. Her action sometimes cause imbalance in matrix but Architect is always there to control the effects. Like other agents and programs Oracle and Architect are not bound to matrix, they existed before it and will going to live after it. So this gives Oracle free will of her own, which reflects in her actions.

Some fan conclusions also say that the Black actor and white actor playing the Oracle character are like [Yin and yang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang). But its Architect and Oracle  who act like Yin and yang. Oracle is even wearing yin-yang earrings throughout the third film to indicate this.

Comment: "Oracle is even wearing yin-yang earrings throughout the third film to indicate this" This is brilliant. I will check for it the next time I watch the movies (again).

Comment: @Ankit Sharma, Man : This is not the 3rd matrix, this is the 6th one. They've already destroyed zion 5 times. There have already been 5 anomalies. Neo is the 6th anomaly. The architect says this - "The matrix is older than you know. I prefer counting from the emergence of one integral anomaly to the emergence of the next, in which case this is the sixth version."

Comment: @Tivep didn't remember that part  and not even sure if it does, will revise with more information later.

Answer (score 3):

Based on what the Architect says, to understand the human mind and help the machines make the humans accept the program better they turn to the Oracle.

The oracle is a software which has a more .. human touch.
The oracle doesn't only help understanding the human mind, but also thinks like one.
This is why the oracle takes pleasure in baking cookies, etc.

The problem now is that the Oracle program thinks so much like the humans that it is siding with the humans and trying to help them with their own problems.
This is not the original intent in the creation of the Oracle program.

Though the Oracle is a program, she sees the point of view oh the humans too and plays the "dangerous game of change" to avoid destruction of either sides.